# Which protocol to use for sending JMS messages?

Tags: jms, protocols, message

I need some advise to implement the best protocol (not http, tcp, ...) te send messages.

- Should I send Serialized Objects? (POJO's)
- Should I send technology independent XML messages?
- What would be recommended?
  Both will work, but what is best practice. Sharing a library is not what I prefer, but is it easy to work with XML? Are there better alternatives? Thanks in advance!

I have one server, with a 1000 clients connected. The server delivers *task* to the clients. The clients send information back after executing different tasks.

*How should I send a task to a JMS client with some parameters?*

A task is nothing more than an *action* and some parameters.

- Example: "action=measure; parameters: duration=100sec; samples=100" --> collect 100 samples during 100 seconds.
- Example: "action=config; parameters: set of configuration parameters" --> to change the client configuration
- Example: "action=stop" --> Stop the client (the system wil restart after a daily reboot)

A *report* is nothing more than data.

- Example: "list of 100 values from measurement"
- Example: "the content of a log-file"

I have read many articles, but couldn't find an answer for this question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as "tasks" - what's wrong with the examples you gave?  It sounds perfectly appropriate.  As far as "reports", the only issues I see are delimiters: how to separate "list" from the following text, how to separate the values from each other.  But that should be easy to resolve.  [K.I.S.S](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)

Comment: Is it a good practice to send POJO's serialized? Or should I stick to technology independent XML. Both will work, but what is best practice. Sharing a library is not what I prefer, but is it easy to work with XML? Are there better alternatives? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would avoid serializing POJOs because of the compatibility issues. You need to share the jar, as well as ensure that the serialVersionUID is properly incremented. Otherwise you will have serious versioning issues. For something as simple as what you are describing, why not consider something like json and deserialize as a simple Map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is our current implementation.

We define a protocol with an XSD and let this generate classes (POJO's).
This allows us to marshal/unmarshal the objects and send them as XML objects.

Our XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
           jaxb:version="2.0">

    <!-- Ping
        The server will send a ping to a client and waits for a pong.
    ****************************************************************** -->
    <xs:element name="Ping">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="client" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="message" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <!-- Pong
        The client will send a pong back to the server.
    ****************************************************************** -->
    <xs:element name="Pong">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="client" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="message" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <!-- Alive
        The client will send an alive message when it starts up.
        The time is local client time.
    ****************************************************************** -->
    <xs:element name="Alive">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="client" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="time" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <!-- ... Many more message definitions ...
    ****************************************************************** -->

</xs:schema>
```

Our test class:

```
public class JaxbFacadeTest {

    @Test
    public void testPing() throws JAXBException, SAXException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        System.out.println("testPing");
        Ping ping = new Ping();
        ping.setClient("guid-client");
        ping.setMessage("Ping Message");
        String marshalToString = JaxbFacade.getInstance().marshalToString(ping);
        System.out.println(marshalToString);
    }

    @Test
    public void testPong() throws JAXBException, SAXException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        System.out.println("testPong");
        Pong pong = new Pong();
        pong.setClient("guid-client");
        pong.setMessage("Ping Message");
        String marshalToString = JaxbFacade.getInstance().marshalToString(pong);
        System.out.println(marshalToString);
    }

    @Test
    public void testAlive() throws JAXBException, SAXException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        System.out.println("testAlive");
        Date now = new Date();
        Alive alive = new Alive();
        alive.setClient("guid-client");
        alive.setTime(now.toString());
        String marshalToString = JaxbFacade.getInstance().marshalToString(alive);
        System.out.println(marshalToString);
    }

    //Many more
}
```

The classes are generated with maven:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/xsd</directory>
            <targetPath>com/test/package/client/jaxb</targetPath>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>jaxb</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <generatePackage>com.test.package.client.jaxb</generatePackage>
                <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/xsd</schemaDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```